# Azure linux VM deployment .json failing with inputting a password for deployment

Tags: json, azure-cli

Apologies in advance I am extremely new to this I am trying to run the following code and don't understand the error when attempting to generate a password for his azuredeploy.json runbook (or whatever its called)

```
$ az group deployment create --resource-group ProjectSpaghetti --template-uri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/docker-simple-on-ubuntu/azuredeploy.jsonubuntu/azuredeploy.json

This command is implicitly deprecated because command group 'group deployment' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use 'deployment group' instead.     

Please provide string value for 'adminUsername' (? for help): luke
Please provide string value for 'dnsNameForPublicIP' (? for help): lasagne
Please provide securestring value for 'adminPasswordOrKey' (? for help):
Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 55abf44d-92e4-4a7f-9c0e-ed7e5353d586. {   
"error": {
    "code": "InvalidParameter",
    "message": "The value of parameter linuxConfiguration.ssh.publicKeys.keyData is invalid.",
    "target": "linuxConfiguration.ssh.publicKeys.keyData"
   }
 }
```

I assumed because it used the phrase `"adminPasswordOrKey"` I would be able to use a password of reasonable complexity.  Is that not the case?  I'm a real newb at this just having a play really.

Comment: Is it because of this by chance in the json file?                                                                 
                                                                                                                 "linuxConfiguration": {
      "disablePasswordAuthentication": true,"

Comment: Could you explain your question for more details or samples? Also, the template URI is invalid for us.

Comment: @wildstallionuk Have you had a chance to check the provided solution?

Answer (score 0):

You see this error because you seemed to have provided a password instead of the default **SSH Public key** for the [adminPasswordOrKey parameter](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/docker-simple-on-ubuntu/azuredeploy.parameters.json#L11) that this template parameter expects.

You could take either of the following steps next:

- Pass on the SSH Public key it expects

  If you do not already have one, [generate a new keypair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/mac-create-ssh-keys#create-an-ssh-key-pair) and pass the contents of the public key as follows:

  ```
  az group deployment create --resource-group <resource-group-name> --template-uri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/docker-simple-on-ubuntu/azuredeploy.json --parameters adminPasswordOrKey="ssh-rsa AAAAB..."
  ```
- Specify an alternate authentication mechanism

  Override the [authenticationType](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/docker-simple-on-ubuntu/azuredeploy.json#L43-L53) to accept a `password` instead of a `sshPublicKey`. Check [this blog](https://andreas-wilm.github.io/2019-04-25-arm-template-default-values-in-cli/) for a quick walk through.

You could also set your parameters using a [parameter file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-cli#parameter-files). Check this document for other ways: [Deploy resources with ARM templates and Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-cli)